# Using Mod_rewrite for short URL's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make my url's short using mod rewrite. Somebody told me it can be achieved using htaccess?

Although I'm a novice at php/mysql I will attempt to solve my own problems via google and my limited knowledge. However I know nothing about htaccess, so I'm seeking somebodies help.

I have user profiles located at

http://www.mysite.com/user/index/169

where `169` is the users `id`.

How do I change it to something like mysite.com/username ?

The script I use already uses mod_rewrite to create directories

/user/index are not physical folders.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If your usernames and id values are stored in a MySQL database then Apache won't be able to turn a username into a numeric id. (You could use a RewriteMap to do this conversion, but it would be messy and fragile.)

Instead you could have Apache forward the username to a PHP script, and then have that PHP script serve up the content for that username instead. (Because PHP can query the MySQL database.)

Once you've written a PHP script (call it show_profile.php for instance) which serves up a user profile based on a username, you can use Apache to call this script with the following in a .htaccess file in the top-level public directory:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_profile.php?username=$1
```

This will send a request for `www.mysite.com/user/ExampleUser_1981` to `/show_profile.php?username=ExampleUser_1981` so that you can read the value of the username in your PHP script using the `$_GET['username']` predefined request variable.

Note that this pattern allows usernames to include lowercase (a-z), uppercase (A-Z), digits (0-9), underscores and hyphens. But customise the pattern to allow only those characters which are allowed to appear in usernames on your site.

I don't recommend simply using the www.mysite.com/username pattern because this means you have to add rules to check that the request is not for an actual file, and I think it looks tidier to use the /user/username pattern.